# Related rates for 2 pools

Tags: calculus

I am having trouble seeing how to tackle this problem: Water is pumped from a $20m\times20m$ pool into a round pond of radius 10m.  At a certain moment the water level in the square pool is dropping by 2 cm per minute.  How fast is the water rising in the round pond? I have all my known variables but I do not know how to get the ${dh \over dt}$ of the circular pond.

Comment: You need to express $h$ in terms of the volume of water in the round pool. You can find how fast that volume is changing by seeing how fast the volume of water in the square pool is changing. For that you need a relationship between the height and the volume of water in the square pool.

Comment: Can you find $\dfrac{dV}{dt}$ for the square pool? And then for round pond?

Answer (score 4):

Water is flowing into the round pond at $20\times20\times0.02=8m^3/\text{min}$

Thus $\frac{dV(t)}{dt}=8m^3/\text{min}$
$$V=\pi r^2h=100\pi h\\\frac{dV}{dt}=100\pi\frac{dh}{dt}\\8=100\pi\frac{dh}{dt}\\\frac{dh}{dt}=0.025\ m/\text{min}$$

Comment: Thank you this was extremely helpful

Answer (score 0):

The volume of water in one minute in the square pool that leaves in one minute is $20 m * 20 m * 2 * 10^{-2} m$ which is egal to $8m^3$.

 In the other pool you gain in one minute $\pi*(10m)^2*h$ with h the height. Then you have h by equalizing the two volumes.